# Find weeks where records are not available

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, date

Im building a timesheet/project mgmt app. Users are assigned to Projects. Assignments have start and end dates.

Timesheets have `week_ending_date` which is used to identify for which week the timesheet was created (covers all 7 days).

What I need to find is, the weeks(where the user has a project assigned) which have no timesheets.

**What is my solution?**

I thought of doing:

```
dates = []
assignments = user.project_assignments.pluck("assignment_start_date, assignment_end_date")
assignments.each do |assignment|
  dates << (assignment[0]..assignment[1]).to_a
end
dates.flatten!
```

to get the dates where timesheet must be available. Now I do,

```
Timesheet.all.select('week_ending_date').uniq.map(&:week_ending_date)
```

Now using these week_ending_dates, I can find the dates of each week. And then I can subtract this from the previous `dates`.

Is this a good solution or is there something better?

- A week is said to be empty if there are no timesheets with that 'week_ending_date'
- Week starts on Monday and ends on Sunday
- Database is MySQL
- Rails 4.0 / Ruby 2.0

Comment: What day of the week does the week end on? Also, what database are you using?

Comment: Week starts on Monday and ends on Sunday. I am using MySQL.